# Customize primefaces from SVN

Tags: eclipse, maven, primefaces

I'm trying to checkout Primefaces Project from http://primefaces.googlecode.com/svn/primefaces/trunk/, using 'Maven Project' in Eclipse, but the `src/main/java` folder don't appear after checkout, only `src/main/resources`. I need remove some **css** files from components and I can't do it without sources.

[image]

Comment: could you clarify, you checkout project, and then try to import it as maven project, right?

Comment: yes, i'm import it as a maven project with maven-webapp-archetype.

Comment: why you using archetype? you need to import with current pom.xml, that it have in SVN

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand your question. When i click "Find/Checkout as .." in eclipse, it ask me for create a new project (i choose maven project), so i need choose a archetype. Remeber i don't wanna just use primefaces in my project, i wanna change source code primeface and after recompile.

Comment: do it in separate steps... First a clean checkout... no archetypes or whatever. Then import as maven project, also without archetypes